# ServiceStack ORMLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We are migrating our SProc based solution over to ORMLite, and so far has been pretty painless. Today I wrote the following method:

```
    public AppUser GetAppUserByUserID(int app_user_id)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(this.ConnectionString, SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);
        AppUser item = null;

        var rh = new RedisHelper();
        var id=  CacheIDHelper.GetAppUserID( app_user_id );
        item = rh.Get<AppUser>(id);

        if (item == null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
                {
                    item = db.Single<AppUser>("application_user_id={0}", app_user_id);

                    rh.Set<AppUser>(item, id);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                APLog.error(ex, "Error retrieving user!");
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
```

I have remove some of the extraneous fields, but they are basically:

```
[Alias("application_user")]
public class AppUser : APBaseObject
{

    [Alias("application_user_id")]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int? UserID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Alias("application_user_guid")]
    public string UserGUID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

 //MORE FIELDS here.

}
```

The challenge is that they only field that is populate is the ID field, AND I already know that ID because I am passing it into the method.

I did get the last SQL called and ran that against the DB directly and all of the fields were being referenced correctly.

I stepped through the code in the debugger, and everything came back correctly, except that the only field returned was the ID.

Thoughts?

Comment: still have issues with this... Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue which was caused by my class methods not mapping to the db properly.  My exact issue was caused by a `nullable` `int` field in the db and the class method was defined as an '`int`' instead of '`int?`'.

Perhaps you have a similar issue?

Comment: This has fixed similar issues for me in the past, although I wish it would throw an error vs a silent log